# ImportError: cannot import name _wapi

Tags: python, py2exe

I have installed py2exe. I am trying a convert a script in to .exe. Here is my setup script.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['Script1.py'])
```

When i run this, I am getting import error. The traceback is given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\z010388-dev\Desktop\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import py2exe
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    patch_distutils()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\patch_distutils.py", line 68, in patch_distutils
    from . import distutils_buildexe
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 91, in <module>
    from . import runtime
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .dllfinder import Scanner, pydll
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\dllfinder.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import _wapi
ImportError: cannot import name _wapi
```

Is anything wrong with my setup script? What is wrong?